# NSTouchBar with multi-level NSPopoverTouchBarItem

Tags: nstouchbar

I'm trying to make a simple `NSTouchBar` with 3 levels of `NSPopoverTouchBarItem`, so basically its like this:

[image: touchbar]
I have the main `NSTouchbar` with 3 `NSButton` and 1 `NSPopoverTouchBarItem` which open the second `NSTouchbar`

The second `NSTouchbar` with 2 `NSButton` and 1 `NSPopoverTouchBarItem` which open the third `NSTouchbar`

The problem is when i try open the 3rd `NSTouchbar`, seems like the 2nd `NSTouchbar` is dismissed, and sometimes doesn't open the 3rd.

Also when opens the third one, when we close, we go to 1st `NSTouchbar`, not the 2nd `NSTouchbar`

Here is the code, should be simple, and should work (**i'm using Xcode TouchBar Simulator**)

```
#import "Window.h"

static NSTouchBarCustomizationIdentifier TouchBarCustomizationIdentifier    = @"TouchBarCustomizationIdentifier";

static NSTouchBarItemIdentifier NSTouchBarItemIdentifier1                   = @"NSTouchBarItemIdentifier1";
static NSTouchBarItemIdentifier NSTouchBarItemIdentifier2                   = @"NSTouchBarItemIdentifier2";
static NSTouchBarItemIdentifier NSTouchBarItemIdentifier3                   = @"NSTouchBarItemIdentifier3";
static NSTouchBarItemIdentifier NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4                   = @"NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4";

static NSTouchBarItemIdentifier NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_1                 = @"NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_1";
static NSTouchBarItemIdentifier NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_2                 = @"NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_2";
static NSTouchBarItemIdentifier NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3                 = @"NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3";

static NSTouchBarItemIdentifier NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3_1               = @"NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3_1";
static NSTouchBarItemIdentifier NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3_2               = @"NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3_2";

@implementation Window

- (NSTouchBar*) makeTouchBar {

    _touchBar1 = [[NSTouchBar alloc] init];
    [_touchBar1 setDelegate:self];
    [_touchBar1 setCustomizationIdentifier:TouchBarCustomizationIdentifier];

    [_touchBar1 setDefaultItemIdentifiers:@[
                                            NSTouchBarItemIdentifier1,
                                            NSTouchBarItemIdentifier2,
                                            NSTouchBarItemIdentifier3,
                                            NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4,
                                            ]
     ];
    [_touchBar1 setCustomizationRequiredItemIdentifiers:@[
                                                          NSTouchBarItemIdentifier1,
                                                          NSTouchBarItemIdentifier2,
                                                          NSTouchBarItemIdentifier3,
                                                          NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4,
                                                          ]
     ];

    return _touchBar1;
}

- (nullable NSTouchBarItem *)touchBar:(NSTouchBar *)touchBar makeItemForIdentifier:(NSTouchBarItemIdentifier)identifier {

    if ([identifier isEqual:NSTouchBarItemIdentifier1]) {

        NSCustomTouchBarItem *customTouchBarItem = [[NSCustomTouchBarItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier];
        [customTouchBarItem setView:[NSButton buttonWithTitle:@"IS TOUCH 1" target:self action:nil]];

        return customTouchBarItem;

    } else if ([identifier isEqual:NSTouchBarItemIdentifier2]) {

        NSCustomTouchBarItem *customTouchBarItem = [[NSCustomTouchBarItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier];

        [customTouchBarItem setView:[NSButton buttonWithTitle:@"IS TOUCH1" target:self action:nil]];

        return customTouchBarItem;

    } else if ([identifier isEqual:NSTouchBarItemIdentifier3]) {

        NSCustomTouchBarItem *customTouchBarItem = [[NSCustomTouchBarItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier];

        [customTouchBarItem setView:[NSButton buttonWithTitle:@"IS TOUCH1" target:self action:nil]];

        return customTouchBarItem;

    } else if ([identifier isEqual:NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4]) {

        NSPopoverTouchBarItem *customTouchBarItem = [[NSPopoverTouchBarItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier];
        [customTouchBarItem setCollapsedRepresentationLabel:@"OPEN TOUCH 2"];

        _touchBar2 = [[NSTouchBar alloc] init];
        [_touchBar2 setDelegate:self];
        [_touchBar2 setCustomizationIdentifier:TouchBarCustomizationIdentifier];

        [_touchBar2 setDefaultItemIdentifiers:@[
                                                NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_1,
                                                NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_2,
                                                NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3,
                                                ]
         ];
        [_touchBar2 setCustomizationRequiredItemIdentifiers:@[
                                                              NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_1,
                                                              NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_2,
                                                              NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3,
                                                              ]
         ];

        [customTouchBarItem setPopoverTouchBar:_touchBar2];

        return customTouchBarItem;

    } else if ([identifier isEqual:NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_1]) {

        NSCustomTouchBarItem *customTouchBarItem = [[NSCustomTouchBarItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier];

        [customTouchBarItem setView:[NSButton buttonWithTitle:@"IS TOUCH 2" target:self action:nil]];

        return customTouchBarItem;

    } else if ([identifier isEqual:NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_2]) {

        NSCustomTouchBarItem *customTouchBarItem = [[NSCustomTouchBarItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier];

        [customTouchBarItem setView:[NSButton buttonWithTitle:@"IS TOUCH 2" target:self action:nil]];

        return customTouchBarItem;

    } else if ([identifier isEqual:NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3]) {

        NSPopoverTouchBarItem *customTouchBarItem = [[NSPopoverTouchBarItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier];
        [customTouchBarItem setCollapsedRepresentationLabel:@"OPEN TOUCH 3"];

        _touchBar3 = [[NSTouchBar alloc] init];
        [_touchBar3 setDelegate:self];
        [_touchBar3 setCustomizationIdentifier:TouchBarCustomizationIdentifier];

        [_touchBar3 setDefaultItemIdentifiers:@[
                                                NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3_1,
                                                NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3_2,
                                                ]
         ];
        [_touchBar3 setCustomizationRequiredItemIdentifiers:@[
                                                              NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3_1,
                                                              NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3_2,
                                                              ]
         ];

        [customTouchBarItem setPopoverTouchBar:_touchBar3];


        return customTouchBarItem;

    } else if ([identifier isEqual:NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3_1]) {

        NSCustomTouchBarItem *customTouchBarItem = [[NSCustomTouchBarItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier];

        [customTouchBarItem setView:[NSButton buttonWithTitle:@"IS TOUCH 3" target:self action:nil]];

        return customTouchBarItem;

    } else if ([identifier isEqual:NSTouchBarItemIdentifier4_3_2]) {

        NSCustomTouchBarItem *customTouchBarItem = [[NSCustomTouchBarItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier];

        [customTouchBarItem setView:[NSButton buttonWithTitle:@"IS TOUCH 3" target:self action:nil]];

        return customTouchBarItem;

    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in Apple's SDK. Another reason is that I can't find any system touch bars with two levels of popovers like you are trying to implement. What I suggest is using a Scrubber like in Apple's [NSTouchBar Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NSTouchBarCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017550) to fit more items into only two levels of popovers (at least until they fix it).

Answer (score 0):

Apple says popovers cannot have popovers, so you can only have a bar and a popover, not a popover inside a popover.

This is what they have posted in their forum to answer a similar question:

[image]

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/78730